# How come my http://fitness.stackexchange.com/ account does not appear in the network profile?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

All the rest do appear, just this one doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the accounts tab on one of the sites, click the `Clear All Associations` button. You'll then be able to re-associate everything back together which should fix things up (give it a few minutes for the cache to refresh).